# Why does not my <<ComboboxSelected>> binding work with custom tkinter combo boxes?

Tags: python, tkinter, project

In my code I am looking at trying to allow the user to click on the Combobox. When they click on the box it will display class names held in my database (that part works). However, I have a function called 'class_id' which does not seem to be called. I am calling it through the use of the binding: "<>. This binding worked for normal tkinter combo boxes, but not with custom tkinter.

The class ID is not being printed as the function is not being called.

Here is my code (this is part of a bigger program):

```
#making use of a nested class
    #'renaming class' is a functionality that belongs to the 'Classes' class so I made use of a nested class
    #'Rename_ Class_Details' is the child class inheriting from the 'Classes' class  
    class Rename_Class_Details:
        def __init__(self,parent):
            #function is called to create the frame for creating a class
            self.parent = parent
            
            self.rename_class()#calling function

        def rename_class(self):
            #function packs all labels etc for user to select which class they would like to update
            self.update_class_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.parent.classFrame)
            self.update_class_frame.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.3)

            #giving title to frame so that user knows what its purpose is
            self.update_description = ctk.CTkLabel(
                self.update_class_frame,
                text="Rename Class",
                font=ctk.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold")
            )
            self.update_description.grid(row=0,column=0)

            self.rename_class_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.update_class_frame, text="Class:")
            self.rename_class_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
            self.rename_class_options = ctk.CTkComboBox(self.update_class_frame, state="readonly")
            self.rename_class_options.grid(row=1,column=1)
            self.rename_class_options.bind("<Button-1>", self.showing_classes)#binding button to function
            self.rename_class_options.bind("<<ComboBoxSelected>>", self.class_id)#binding selected input to function

            self.change_name_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.update_class_frame, text="Change name to:")
            self.change_name_label.grid(row=2,column=0)
            self.change_name_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.update_class_frame)
            self.change_name_entry.grid(row=2,column=1)

            self.rename_btn = ctk.CTkButton(self.update_class_frame, text="Update Name")
            self.rename_btn.grid(row=3,column=1)
           # self.rename_btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.update_name)#binding button to function

            for widget in self.update_class_frame.winfo_children():
                widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=10)
                #for loop that loops through all widgets
                #assinging all widgets with same amount of padding

        def showing_classes(self,event):
            #function is called so that combobox shows all classes for user to select from
            connection = sqlite3.connect("Teacher.db")
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            checking_table_existence = """SELECT name from sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='Classes'"""
            cursor.execute(checking_table_existence)
            exists = cursor.fetchone()

            if exists:
                optionSelectingClasses= [] #holds all classes in a list

                classTable = "SELECT [Class Name] FROM Classes"
                cursor.execute(classTable)

                selectTestClasses = cursor.fetchall()#fetches all fields within specified column

                #for loop that loops through all fields within column and adds entries into 'optionSelectingClasses' variable as a list
                for a in selectTestClasses:
                    optionSelectingClasses.append(str(a[0]))
                print(optionSelectingClasses)#seeing if all classes show

                self.rename_class_options.configure(values=optionSelectingClasses)
                #Combobox now shows all values (class names) within the 'Class Name' compile
                
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "There are no classes to select from!") 

        def class_id(self,event):
            #function is called so that when the user selects a class it retrieves it class ID
            connection = sqlite3.connect("Teacher.db")
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            class_selection = self.rename_class_options.get()

            selecting_class = """SELECT [Class Name], [ClassID] from Classes"""
            cursor.execute(selecting_class)
            classRecords = cursor.fetchall()

            for i in classRecords:
                if class_selection == i[0]:
                    self.classID = i[1]
            print(self.classID)#printing to see if correct ID is printed
```

The classes do show, but the class ID is not being printed. The reason being is because the function is not being called in the first place. The function works with 'ttk' but not with CTk (custom tkinter).

Answer (score 1):

Note that `customtkinter.CTkComboBox` does not inherit from `ttk.Combobox`, so it does not generate the virtual event `<<ComboboxSelected>>` (note also that it is not `<<ComboBoxSelected>>`).

However you can use the `command` option of `customtkinter.CTkComboBox` to get similar effect:

```py
def rename_class(self):
    ...
    self.rename_class_options = ctk.CTkComboBox(self.update_class_frame, state="readonly",
                                                command=self.class_id)
    ...
    # binding not needed
    #self.rename_class_options.bind("<<ComboBoxSelected>>", self.class_id)#binding selected input to function
    ...

def class_id(self, class_selection):
    #function is called so that when the user selects a class it retrieves it class ID
    connection = sqlite3.connect("Teacher.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # the selected value will be passed as argument
    # so don't need to get it here
    #class_selection = self.rename_class_options.get()

    selecting_class = """SELECT [Class Name], [ClassID] from Classes"""
    cursor.execute(selecting_class)
    classRecords = cursor.fetchall()

    for i in classRecords:
        if class_selection == i[0]:
            self.classID = i[1]
            print(self.classID)#printing to see if correct ID is printed
```